# OAuth2 Requesting Additional Scopes

Tags: ios, google-api, google-signin, google-oauth

Using the Google Sign In SDK, a user can sign in via OAuth2 with some default scopes requested. It can be beneficial to not request every scope an app may need up front, and instead to request additional scopes at a later time so as to not overwhelm the user at sign up.

Google outlines the process for doing this [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/additional-scopes).

The issue is that, after a user has signed in with Google, upon requesting additional scopes the user has the ability to switch Google accounts and authorize those scopes using a different account before returning to my application.

Is there a way, similar to calling -[GIDSignIn signIn], to explicitly specify which user I want to signIn and not allow the option of changing accounts?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Google Sign in SDK.  Most of what I have done has been written myself so I don't know how that SDK really works.    However that being said the Authentication server does support something called Login_hint which should allow you to force them to use a specific user.

> [login_hint](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent)   email address or sub identifier When your application
>   knows which user it is trying to authenticate, it can provide this
>   parameter as a hint to the Authentication Server. Passing this hint
>   will either pre-fill the email box on the sign-in form or select the
>   proper multi-login session, thereby simplifying the login flow.

More info

> [login_hint](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) can be the user's email address or the sub string,
>   which is equivalent to the user's Google ID. If you do not provide a
>   login_hint and the user is currently logged in, the consent screen
>   includes a request for approval to release the user’s email address to
>   your app. (Read more at [login_hint](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#login-hint).)

If memory services Google Sign in SDK does work with openId connect so it should be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried setting the loginHint parameter to the user's email, and although it does seem to no longer display any other google accounts when asking to choose an account, it still displays the "Use another account" button. This is certainly an improvement, however it still leaves the user with the ability to sign in to another account.